# Keyboard shortcut with gnome-terminal not working

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, gnome, gnome-terminal

I want to execute a command from terminal which uses the output of another command as an argument, so I used $ operator as in

```
sudo arpspoof -i wlan0 $(/sbin/ip route | awk '/default/ { print $3 }')
```

The above command works fine if I execute it from a terminal,
However I want to run the same command as a keyboard shortcut, on adding the keyboard shortcut with command

```
gnome-terminal -e "sudo arpspoof -i wlan0 $(/sbin/ip route | awk '/default/ { print $3 }')"
```

is not delivering me the result. The terminal opens up as expected, however on entering the password the terminal closes abruptly.
 It also works fine if I use static argument as in

```
gnome-terminal -e "sudo arpspoof -i wlan0 192.168.0.1"
```

It is a command that  will never exit, it will execute for infinity.

Comment: Where are you adding that shortcut? How is it set up exactly? Is that command supposed to stay running until you kill it?

Comment: Here my arpspoof is a command that will never exit, I have edited my question accordingly.